# setting cookies between nestjs backend and nextjs 14

Tags: typescript, next.js, cookies, nestjs, next-auth

i'm having issues settings the cookeis coming from a nestjs backend into my nextjs app.

my nestjs app runs on the port 3001 and this is my bootstrap

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true,
  });

  app.use(cookieParser());
  await app.listen(3001);
}
bootstrap();
```

to test it, i've made a get endpoint

```
  @Get()
  async getAll(@Req() request: Request, @Res() response: Response) {

    console.log(request.cookies);
    response.cookie('name', 'value', {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false,
      sameSite: 'none',
    });

    return response.send('ok');
   }
```

in nextjs in the src/app/api/signin/route.ts file i have this

```
'use server'

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import axios, { AxiosHeaderValue } from 'axios';
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export async function POST(request: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {

  const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/test", {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    withCredentials: true,
  });

  console.log(response.headers)

  return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(response.data))
}
```

all good, the console.log prints the set-cookie

```
Object [AxiosHeaders] {
  'x-powered-by': 'Express',
  'access-control-allow-origin': 'http://localhost:3000',
  vary: 'Origin',
  'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
  'set-cookie': [ 'name=value; Path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=None' ],
  'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
  'content-length': '2',
  etag: 'W/"2-eoX0dku9ba8cNUXvu/DyeabcC+s"',
  date: 'Tue, 19 Mar 2024 09:45:14 GMT',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'keep-alive': 'timeout=5'
}
```

NICE!

but if i call the same endpoint again, the `console.log(request.cookies);` in the backend i get null.

shouldn't the set-cookie directive set the cookie in the backend? and with axios withCredentials it should use them, right?

what am i missing? i might be confusing stuff, because the nextjs tutorials are quite wacky, and i'm trying to do something that should be relatively simple but i've been banging my head around this for the past 2 days and i can't seem to set the cookies on the request...

Answer (score 2):

Your [NestJS backend](https://docs.nestjs.com/) is configured to accept requests from your Next.js application running on `localhost:3000` and to set cookies on the client.

```bash
NestJS App (Port 3001) ──> Enable CORS for Next.js App (Port 3000)
   │
   └── Set-Cookie on Response
```

In your [Next.js app](https://nextjs.org/learn-pages-router/basics/create-nextjs-app), you are making a request to the NestJS backend and expecting the cookies to be saved and sent back on subsequent requests.

```bash
Next.js App (Port 3000) ──> Axios Request to NestJS (Port 3001)
   │                             │
   │ <── Set-Cookie [name=value] │
   │                             │
   └── Subsequent Request ───────┘
       (Expecting Cookies)
```

When you make an HTTP request from your Next.js server-side code (using [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)), the `set-cookie` header is indeed received by your Next.js application, as you show in your logs.

However, these cookies need to be explicitly set on the client's browser to be included in subsequent requests automatically. Axios (or any server-side HTTP request library) does not automatically handle cookies like a browser does.

```js
'use server';

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import axios from 'axios';

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  const backendResponse = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/test", {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json" // This header is included for completeness but is optional for GET requests
    },
    withCredentials: true,
  });

  // Extract cookies from the Axios response
  const setCookieHeader = backendResponse.headers['set-cookie'];

  // Create a new NextResponse object with the backend response data
  const response = new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(backendResponse.data), {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  });

  // If there are cookies, set them in the NextResponse headers to forward them to the client
  if (setCookieHeader) {
    response.headers.set('Set-Cookie', setCookieHeader.join(','));
  }

  return response;
}
```

Comment: it's not working, i guess i have done something really wrong in the setup between next and nest. i'll start from scratch and i set up everything up again.
thanks for the answers anyways :)

Comment: @ChristmasFighters OK, let me know how it goes. Make sure CORS settings on the NestJS side correctly allow requests from the Next.js application domain. Mismatched or overly restrictive settings can prevent cookies from being set or sent. And make sure the cookies' attributes (such as `SameSite`, `Secure`, and `Domain`) are compatible with the testing environment. For example, `Secure` cookies require an HTTPS connection, and `SameSite=None` requires `Secure`.

Answer (score 0):

"httpOnly" cookies by design are not accessible via JavaScript. You can only set it from the nestjs backend.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).